# how to properly place input to 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to assign an array to another array problem is it keeps stating undefined offset. Though when I echo'd out the other variables that have a similar format to the one in question they display properly. Please help. Thank you.

```
function searchAllIncoming(){

    $rows[] = array();
    $rows2[] = array();
    $rows3[] = array();

    $i = 0;
    $companyName = $this->db->query("SELECT id, name from company");
    foreach($companyName->result_array() as $row2){
        $rows2[$i]['id'] = $row2['id'];
        $rows2[$i]['name'] = $row2['name'];
        $i++;
    }       
    //get all company names

    $i = 0;
    $staffName = $this->db->query("SELECT id, surname, firstName, middleInitial from employee");
    foreach($staffName->result_array() as $row3){
        $rows3[$i]['id'] = $row3['id'];
        $rows3[$i]['name'] = $row3['surname'].", ".$row3['firstName']." ".$row3['middleInitial'];
        $i++;
    }
    //get all employee names

    $i= 0;
    $output = $this->db->query("SELECT * from incoming ORDER BY incomingId LIMIT 20");

    foreach($output->result_array() as $row){
        $count = 0;
        $j = 0;
        $rows[$i]['incomingId'] = $row['incomingId'];
        $rows[$i]['referenceNo'] = $row['referenceNo'];
        $rows[$i]['documentTypeId'] = $row['referenceNo'];
        $rows[$i]['documentDate'] = $row['documentDate'];
        $rows[$i]['dateReceived'] = $row['dateReceived'];
        $rows[$i]['sender'] = $row['sender'];

        while($count < sizeof($rows2)){
            if($rows2[$j]['id'] != $row['companyId']){
            $j++;
            } else {
                $rows[$i]['companyName'] = $rows2[$j]['name'];
                break;
            }
        }
        $j= 0;

        while($count < sizeof($rows3)){
            if($rows3[$j]['id'] != $row[$i]['responsibleStaffId']){
                $j++;
            } else {
                $rows[$i]['responsibleStaffName'] = $rows3[$j]['name'];
                break;
            }
        }

        $rows[$i]['subject'] = $row['subject'];
        $rows[$i]['actionDone'] = $row['actionDone'];

        $rows[$i]['track'] = $row['track'];
        $rows[$i]['completed'] = $row['completed'];
        $rows[$i]['remarks'] = $row['remarks'];
        $i++;
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

My error occurs at:

```
$rows[$i]['responsibleStaffName']

and   

$rows[$i]['companyName']
```

Comment: you might wanna put that related info inside your question (edit).

Answer (score 0):

The two while loop you have in your code, it might go with a infinite loop.
If the "if condition" will always evaluates to true, then it will definitely be a infinite loop. Please increase the $count value after every loop, like below.

```
while($count < sizeof($rows2)){
    if($rows2[$j]['id'] != $row['companyId']){
        $j++;
    } else {
        $rows[$i]['companyName'] = $rows2[$j]['name'];
        break;
    }

    ++$count;
}
```

Please try with the above code, it might help you to debug where is the actual fault.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
$rows3[$j]['id'] != $row[$i]['responsibleStaffId'];
```

should just be

```
$rows3[$j]['id'] != $row['responsibleStaffId'];
```